# fetching and displaying data with CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

EDIT: 2. I have resolved the issue! To see the final version, look at this pastebin and see the difference between it and my code here on StackOverflow.

http://pastebin.com/yWqs86Zt

EDIT. I now am able to print the data on screen but I am seeing all the planet data when I only want a row per ctp. (earth row on the earth.ctp etc).

New to cake and very much confused. I have looked over the documents but am still at a loss. Big props to anyone who can help a student developer out.

In all I am working on an application which shows data on each planet and moon in the solar system, passing varchars of data from the Database to the whateverplanet.ctp.

I am trying to display a row per ctp. Such as earth info on Planets/earth.ctp by calling the planet_name/info/content columns in the PlanetsController earth() function.

I have a database with two tables

- planets table

  - planet_id (int)
  - planet_name (varchar)
  - planet_info (varchar)
  - planet_content (varchar)

And a moons table with the same set up just with moons instead of planets.

Planet Model looks like

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model'); 
class Planet extends AppModel {

        public $name = 'Planet';
        public $useTable = 'planets';
} 

?>
```

Controller is as this (with commented out attempts)

```
<?php

class PlanetsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Planets';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function earth() {

         $this->set('planets', $this->Planet->find('all'));

    }
}
?>
```

earth.ctp looks like this

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('earth1.jpg'); ?>

    <h2> Fact File </h2>
    <?php foreach ($planets as $planet): ?>

            <h3><?php echo $planet['Planet']['planet_name']; ?></h3>

            <p> <?php echo $planet['Planet']['planet_info']; ?></p>


            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <!--<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum mattis turpis id aliquam. Duis vitae magna in justo varius dapibus. Donec mattis nunc tellus, at sollicitudin risus rutrum in. Curabitur vehicula et ipsum vel fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum venenatis eros gravida nibh eleifend egestas. Quisque vel libero convallis, vulputate sem nec, sollicitudin nisl. Nullam egestas orci eget velit hendrerit rhoncus.</p>-->
</div><!-- /.col-xs-12 main -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$earth = $this->Planet->find('first', array('conditions' => array('planet_name' => 'Earth')));
$this->set('earth', $earth);
```

Or you can use find('all') as well if you expect more rows.

Btw you should name the 'planet_id' column 'id'; read more at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: Thanks, I got all my planets to print out on my earth.ctp view. How would I only display the info earth row in the planets table? I have updated my original with the working code from the controller and view which loads all of the data. Sorry again, I have looked through the book and still cannot wrap my head about it.

Comment: Did you try to set the conditions for the find method (what I wrote in this answer)?

Comment: I tried it but it gave back this error [: Undefined variable: planets [APP\View\Planets\earth.ctp, line 10] & Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Planets\earth.ctp, line 10]

Line 10 is <?php foreach ($planets as $planet): ?>

Comment: Because you didn't set the $planets variable for the View. If you use the example from this answer you should use $earth variable in your View.

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused. I replaced $planets with $earth and it now reports that line 12 and 14 are: Undefined index: Planet [APP\View\Planets\earth.ctp, line 12]

Comment: Debug the variable so you can see the data structure: <?php debug($earth); ?> If you use find('first') you don't need a foreach loop. It returns a little bit different array than find('all'). You should read this page again: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first

Comment: Thanks!. I've tried to debug with <?php debug($earth); ?> but still at a loss. First time using cake and I am seriously getting lost.

I get this '': Undefined variable: earth [APP/View/Planets/earth.ctp, line 11'' and /app/View/Planets/earth.ctp (line 11) null

Comment: You didn't set the `$earth` variable in the controller. Do you have this line of code in the controller: `$this->set('earth', $earth);`? Anyway please show your PlanetsController.php and earth.ctp files. Use pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: Here is the PlanetsController and earth.ctp file in pastebin. Thanks again for putting up with my silly confusion. First MVC and PHP framework I've worked with.

http://pastebin.com/styUZKS0

Comment: In the controller, after the find put this: `debug($earth);`. What is the output? In the view you don't need the foreach, check the comment #6.

Comment: Added debug controller and removed the foreach in the ctp. I got the following at the top left of my view. \app\Controller\PlanetsController.php (line 13)

Comment: The `find` doesn't give any results. Is the name of the column `planet_name`? Is there any row in the database with the `Earth` value at that field?

Comment: The table name is 'planets' and the fields columns are planet_id, planet_name, planet_info, planet_content.

in planet_name I have 'Earth' as varchar and info/content are also large varchars. planet_id is of course the id field so 'Earth' is currently '1' since it's the first one I created.

Comment: What does this output? Place this line into the controller.
`debug($this->Planet->find('all'));`

Comment: This is what I have

    `public function earth() {
            
            
             $earth = $this->Planet->find('first', array('conditions' => array('planet_name' => 'Earth')));
$this->set('earth', $earth);

            debug($this->Planet->find('all')); 
             
            
 }
`
And the output is the same. \app\Controller\PlanetsController.php (line 13) and a white box stretched across the screen with no info.

Confusing, I can get my planets (Earth and Venus) to display in the .ctp with find('all')

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the model?

Comment: Still stuck on this. Im close but I feel I might just be confusing myself. If you have time, would you care to join me in a chat?

Answer (score 0):

you should come back to cakephp docs , review HtmlHelper, 
then check this again:

> 'Html' => array('className' => 'BoostCakeHtml'),
>       'Form' => array('className' => 'BoostCakeForm'),
>       'Paginator' => array('className' => 'BoostCakePaginator'),

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying I should not be using BoostCake? I am using bootstrap as my front end.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code snippet you commented out:

```
//$earth = $this->Earth->find('all');
//$this->set('planets');
```

First, your model is named `Planet` but with `$this->Earth` you try to access a (non-existing) model called `Earth`.

In the second line you define a variable for the view, but you don't assign a value to it.

Fixing those two issues, you get something like:

```
$this->set('planets', $this->Planet->find('all'));
```

Comment: That worked but it prints out all of the data in the planets table. How would I output only the earth row (planet_name/info/content for the earth.ctp? Thanks again!

Comment: @stejdm You have to specify some conditions, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: Thanks! So I would have to use it like

`public function earth() {
    // ...
    $planets = $this->Planet->find('all');
    $pending = $this->Planet->find('all', array(
        'planet_name' 'planet_info' 'planet_content' => array('Planet.status' => 'pending')
    ));
}`

Comment: @stejdm This will cause a syntax error ;-)  But I see you got it right in the code you posted on pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks! I am really grateful for the help here! I just cant wrap my head around how to get the earth row to display on the earth.ctp It's always the simple things that get you!

Comment: @stejdm add a `debug($earth);` statement to your view, this will show you the structure of the data your view received from the controller

Comment: I tried this with rocknrollcanneverdie below. This was my outcome.  I've tried to debug with <?php debug($earth); ?> but still at a loss. First time using cake and I am seriously getting lost. I get this '': Undefined variable: earth [APP/View/Planets/earth.ctp, line 11'' and /app/View/Planets/earth.ctp (line 11) null

Comment: Still stuck on this. Im close but I feel I might just be confusing myself. If you have time, would you care to join me in a chat?

Comment: Good to see you could fix the issue in the meantime :)