# CakePHP Model display all data null

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

**I can not display the data.**

My model (app/Model/Product.php)

```
class Product extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Product'; 
}
```

My controller (app/Controller/ProductsController.php):

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
public $components = array('Session');
public $name = 'Products';

public function ver($id = null) {
$this->Product->id_producto = $id;
debug($this->Product->id_producto); //Show id with value Ex. 12,34,...
$this->set('products', $this->Product->read());
  }
}
```

My view (app/View/ver.ctp):

```
<?php debug($product['Product']['nombre']); ?> // Show 'null'
<h2><?php echo $product['Product']['nombre']?></h2></td></tr>
<strong>Descripci&oacute;n:</strong> <?php echo $product['Product']['descripcion']?> <br/>
<small>Fecha de registro: <?php echo $product['Product']['fecha_reg']?></small> <br/>
<small>Última modificación: <?php echo $product['Product']['Fecha_mod']?></small>
```

Comment: check out http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819451/fetching-and-displaying-data-with-cakephp-2-x-solved  As @nedstark said, you should use `find`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the default primary key: `id`. Define your primary key in your **model**:

```
class Product extends AppModel
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id_producto';
}
```

... and assing requesting product id to `id` in your **controller**. `id` will match to primary key `id_producto` in your database table:

```
public function ver($id = null) 
{
    $this->Product->id = $id;
    debug($this->Product->id); //Show id with value Ex. 12,34,...;
    $this->set('product', $this->Product->read());
}
```

Some notes:

In your **controller** you assign the results to plural 'products':

```
$this->set('products', $this->Product->read());
```

But in your **view** you use the variable in singular `$product`:

Try to use `<?php debug($products['Product']['nombre']); ?>` instead.

Comment: `debug($products);` is probably more useful - since that definitely exists.

Comment: Thank's very much! You are excelent!